# ArrayList. Strange things

Tags: java

I have the code:

```
private class Record {
    byte year;
    float val;
}
Record record=new Record();
List<Record> recList = new ArrayList<Record>();
...
//now I add first element to array list
record.year=12;
record.val=55;
recList.add(record);

//now I add second element to array list
record.year=13;
record.val=77;
recList.add(record);
```

As you see I add different elements.
But as a result all elements in array list are the same.
So adding 2-nd, 3-d... element changes all previous elements
to the values of last "record".
What's wrong? Thanks?

Comment: You need to create a `new` instance of `Record` for each item you want to add to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate new objects so they are physically different objects.  Right now, you only have one object that is in the ArrayList multiple times.

```
Record record = new Record();
```

Also, you should add hashCode() and equals() to Record since you are working with collections.

Answer (score 3):

An `ArrayList` keeps a list of **references** to objects. You're always modifying the same original object which means the reference is the same, but its values differ.

You can fix it by explicitly assigning a new instance to the `record` variable:

```
record.year=12;
record.val=55;
recList.add(record);


record = new Record();
record.year=13;
record.val=77;
recList.add(record);
```

Answer (score 1):

> As you see I add different elements

No, you just edited old `Record` object and added it again. Each time before you add `Record` object you need to crate `new` one.